# Properties of a norm 3

Tags: normed-spaces

I know that to define a norm, four properties need to be true:
norm(x)>=0,
norm(x)=0 if and only if x=0,
norm(ax) = |a| norm(x) with 'a' a scalar,
norm(x+y)<=norm(x)+norm(y).

Our teacher mentioned that in he thought that you could derive the first and the second property of the fourth one. But he wasn't sure.
I tried to find this out, but I didn't succeed.

Does anyone know how to derive this or was the teacher wrong and do you really need to check the four properties when defining a norm?

Comment: You also need the third, $\lVert x + (-x)\rVert$ …

Answer (score 0):

It is false, indeed define $n(\cdot)\,\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+\,z\rightarrow|\Re(z)|$.

It respects the first, the third and the fourth axioms, but the second fails since $n(i)=0$ even if $i\neq0$